# How alias_method work in ruby. How can I use it to achieve DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I saw this line of code in an application but was unable to find the method 
get_accounts in whole application.

```
  alias_method :get_accounts, :get_list_of_records
```

Comment: this isn't really about DRY, its about supporting legacy method naming. Its a way to keep your naming what you want and at the same time support people that are upgrading your library and using the old method name. You can also add some methods that will throw deprecation warnings if you want to get ride of these methods eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_accounts` is an alias method for `get_list_of_records`. Nothing wrong with the fact that it had never been used *(except for the fact that it redundant and confusing)*. Probably, everywhere in code was used and original name of the method `get_list_of_records`. As it's not used anywhere, you can safely delete this line to avoid any further confusion.